# i need to give admin rights to upload images for an ecommerce website using react and nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, e-commerce, image-upload

i am creating an ecommerce website using NextJs. i want to give admin rights where admin can upload an product image which will be displayed later on dashboard along with the product.

My question is how to achieve this?? i can store the image location in db along with other product details but what about image?? where to store this uplaoded image so that it can be automatically displayed on page load.

one way would be to load images in file system where app is served but then i would have to deploy app again and again and this seems impractical. Also i dont think there is way to directly load images to public folder.

Looking forward to answers.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically do it like you would do it in **React**. Create a component which handles the displaying of the preview as well as the upload to an external server. I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/QWGpeoL) for you to test the component in the wild. It consists of this:

```
import React from "react";

const ImageUpload = props => {
  const [currentFile, setFile] = React.useState();
  const [previewImage, setPreview] = React.useState();
  const [success, setSuccess] = React.useState(false);

  const selectFile = function (e) {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);

    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setPreview(reader.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const submit = function () {
    let fd = new FormData();

    fd.append("file", currentFile);

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function (state) {
      if (
        state.originalTarget.readyState === 4 &&
        state.originalTarget.status === 200
      ) {
        setSuccess(true);
      }
    };

    request.open(
      "POST",
      "https://us-central1-tutorial-e6ea7.cloudfunctions.net/fileUpload",
      true
    );
    request.send(fd);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Upload an image</h1>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={selectFile} />

      {previewImage && !success && (
        <div>
          <img className="preview" src={previewImage} alt="" />
        </div>
      )}

      {success && <div>Image successfully uploaded</div>}

      <button onClick={submit}>Upload</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageUpload;
```

- An `<img/>` element which accepts files and renders a preview in an `onChange` event using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader) api.
- A `submit` function which uses the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader) interface to append the image and uses [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to upload the file to the server.
- Some simple UI logic to display the preview to the user.

Check out this [tutorial](https://w3path.com/react-image-upload-or-file-upload-with-preview/) for a more detailed explanation.